# Sum and difference of tangents in degrees

Tags: trigonometry

$$\tan81^\circ-\tan63^\circ-\tan27^\circ+\tan9^\circ$$
At first, I tried to break the tangent into multiple angles…
$$\text{FAILED}$$
Then I proceeded by converting it into other trigonometric ratios…
$$\text{FAILED}$$
Please suggest me an approach to such questions. A solution is most welcomed.

Comment: Rearrange the above expression -  $\tan 81 + \tan 9 - (\tan 63 + \tan 27)$. which formula should u use now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
  \tan 81^{\circ}-\tan 63^{\circ}-\tan 27^{\circ}+\tan 9^{\circ} &=
  \tan (90^{\circ}-9^{\circ})-\tan (90^{\circ}-27^{\circ})-
  \tan 27^{\circ}+\tan 9^{\circ} \\
  &= \cot 9^{\circ}-\cot 27^{\circ}-\tan 27^{\circ}+\tan 9^{\circ} \\
  &= \frac{\cos 9^{\circ}}{\sin 9^{\circ}}+
     \frac{\sin 9^{\circ}}{\cos 9^{\circ}}-
     \frac{\cos 27^{\circ}}{\sin 27^{\circ}}-
     \frac{\sin 27^{\circ}}{\cos 27^{\circ}} \\
  &=
  \frac{\cos^2 9^{\circ}+\sin^2 9^{\circ}}{\sin 9^{\circ} \cos 9^{\circ}}-
  \frac{\cos^2 27^{\circ}+\sin^2 27^{\circ}}{\sin 27^{\circ} \cos 27^{\circ}} \\
  &= \frac{1}{\sin 9^{\circ} \cos 9^{\circ}}-
     \frac{1}{\sin 27^{\circ} \cos 27^{\circ}} \\
  &= \frac{2}{\sin 18^{\circ}}-
     \frac{2}{\sin 54^{\circ}} \\
  &= 2(1+\sqrt{5})-2(\sqrt{5}-1) \\
  &= 4
\end{align*}

Comment: Approach is really impressive...Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: We have $$\tan(u) + \tan(v) = {\sin(u) \over \cos(u)} + {\sin(v) \over \cos(v)} = {\sin(u)\cos(v) + \cos(u)\sin(v) \over \cos(u)\cos(v)} = {\sin(u + v) \over \cos(u)\cos(v)}$$

Can you see what to do with $\tan(u) - \tan(v)$?